# PhanEnumCannotImplement - Interface not allowed to extend BackedEnum interface

Tags: php, static-analysis

I am creating an interface `SurveyAnswer` that extends `BackedEnum`. I am extending BackedEnum to make sure that the enums that are created are `backed`.

```php
interface SurveyAnswerInterface extends BackedEnum
{
    public static function getQuestion()
}
```

Then I am creating my enums that implements this interface

```php
enum SituationAnswer: string implements SurveyAnswerInterface
{
    case NEW = 'new';
    case OLD = 'old';

    public static function getQuestion()
    {
        return 'What is your situation?';
    }
}
```

This piece of code works perfectly fine.
But `PHP Phan` complains that `SurveyAnswerInterface:10 PhanEnumCannotImplement Classlike SurveyAnswerInterface cannot implement \BackedEnum in php 8.1+`

Comment: I get no phpstan error on PHP 8.2.6 with "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.98".

Comment: @MarkusZeller This error is thrown by phan not phpstan

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Misread that.

Answer (score 1):

The `BackedEnum` interface is applied automatically by the Php engine and is not meant for user implementation. This also applies to all other `Enum` interfaces such as `IntBackedEnum` and `UnitEnum`.

See

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.backedenum.php